# Eclipse doesn't generate google cloud endpoint client library

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to create my first GAE Endpoint app, and instead of generating an endpoint from a class, I'd like to create my own personalised Endpoint... is this possible?

I've written this class:

```
@Api(name="my_endpoint", path="my_endpoint")
public class MyFirstEndpoint {

  @ApiMethod (name="my_method", path="my_method", httpMehod=HttpMethod.GET)
  public Response myMethod(@Named("param1") String param1) {
    ...
  }

}
```

But when I try to generate the Endpoint Client Library in Eclipse, it says that there was an error... and the worst thing is that it doesn't say what error it is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible to create custom Endpoints.

I had the same error. I think you can't use "_" in the name of the Api nor the ApiMethod...

Try using "myEndpoint" and "myMethod" as the names and keep the "_" in the paths.

Comment: To find out what the error is, take a look at the error log under Window -> Show View -> Error Log. We need to expose the error to the user though; you're totally right there.

Answer (score 0):

A bit unrelated to this particular case, but it's the first thing that popped up on Google when searching for the error: you can't have overloaded methods in your Endpoints classes. Found this by looking in the Error console as described above in a comment.