# Method interference in Google Cloud Endpoints with Google Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-eclipse-plugin

I am experiencing a strange behavior while generating endpoints using the Google Appengine Eclipse plugin. I have an endpoint class with over 20 endpoint methods. When I first tried generating the endpoints for android I get the error

```
 Generating Cloud Endpoint has encountered errors and is not complete
```

By way of troubleshooting, I comment out all the methods to find the culprits. What I found is a bit baffling. After uncommenting the 16th method, I get the error again. There are two methods that are interfering with each other! If I comment out one or the other the endpoint is generated fine. But if I have both uncommented, I get the error above.

Does anyone know what may be causing this interference?

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getOrangers", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public FaceList getOrangers(UserRequest request) throws NotFoundException {
    FaceList list = new FaceList();
    return list;
}

@ApiMethod(name = "getMangoers", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public FaceList getMangoers(UserRequest request) throws NotFoundException {
    FaceList list = new FaceList();
    return list;
}
```

I have edited the methods down to their stubs as shown above and still get the same interference problem.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Firstly, when you get an error with that annoying undescriptive message:

> *Generating Cloud Endpoint has encountered errors and is not complete*

you should check the **Error Log** under `Window -> Show View -> Error Log` to get more info.

---

I did so, and I found that the actual exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  Multiple methods with same rest path "POST facelist": "getOrangers" and "getMangoers"
```

So, the problem is that **your 2 methods have the same path**! Adding explicitly a path for your methods will solve the problem:

```
@ApiMethod(name="getOrangers", path="get_oranges", httpMethod=HttpMethod.POST)
public FaceList getOrangers(UserRequest request) throws NotFoundException {
    //...
}

@ApiMethod(name="getMangoers", path="get_mangoers", httpMethod=HttpMethod.POST)
public FaceList getMangoers(UserRequest request) throws NotFoundException {
    //...
}
```

---

*NOTE*: As you didn't set paths for your methods, GPE is generating them automatically. It seems that GPE is generating the same path for the 2 methods, using to form the path the HTTP method (*POST*) and the returned value (*facelist*), which doesn't correspond with what is said in [**Google Cloud Endpoints Documentation**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations):

> "***path***: The URI path to use to access this method. If you don't set
>   this, a default path is used based on the Java **method name**."

It says that the path is automatically generated using the method name, and in that case you'd not getting any error, since your 2 methods have obviously different names. So I guess it must be a bug (as many others) in Endpoints.

Comment: Wow! I hope your reply gets a LOT! of up votes. `Window -> Show View -> Error Log` alone is amazing! Thank you so much! +1 and Check! When I asked that question I actually had no hope of getting an answer. I just asked anyway since I was completely stuck.

Comment: No problem @learner, I'm happy it helped! I had already suggested that *trick* before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945554/can-i-return-a-generic-in-google-cloud-end-point/15946690#15946690) And in fact it was [at]bossylobster who suggested it to me (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684837/eclipse-doesnt-generate-google-cloud-endpoint-client-library/15684863#15684863) As for the upvotes I'd like that, but I don't think so, since these tags don't have too much followers :)

Comment: Complementing:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#path_parameters