# Generate Client Libraries fails if ClassnameEndpoint.java has 'Multiple methods with same rest path "GET classname": etc

Tags: java, rest, android-studio, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

after generating Endpoint from a model class I edit the ClassnameEndpoint file to make a method that will return a list of Entities using a modified SELECT string.

Somehow this makes a clash and Generate Client Libraries fails like this:

INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\1177\AndroidStudioProjects\N5\appN5-AppEngine\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
[ERROR] 
com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.ApiConfigInvalidException: Multiple methods with same rest path "GET eventdata": "listUserEventData" and "listEventData"

here is the ClassnameEndpoint.java, which is edited by hand after being generated:

note listEventData and listUserEventData are identical except for SELECT string...

So how can I create an endpoint method to get ALL the entities and another method to get SOME entities without the clash?

```
package sic.example.appn5;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor;
import com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPACursorHelper;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityExistsException;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Api(name = "eventdataendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "example.sic", ownerName = "example.sic", packagePath = "appn5"))
public class EventDataEndpoint {

    /**
     * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
     * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
     *
     * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
     * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
     */

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "unused"})
    @ApiMethod(name = "listEventData")
    public CollectionResponse<EventData> listEventData(
            @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

        EntityManager mgr = null;
        List<EventData> execute = null;

        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();
            Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from EventData as EventData");
            Cursor cursor;
            if (cursorString != null && cursorString.trim().length() > 0) {
                cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
                query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
            }

            if (limit != null) {
                query.setFirstResult(0);
                query.setMaxResults(limit);
            }

            execute = (List<EventData>) query.getResultList();
            cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
            if (cursor != null) cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

            // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
            // for lazy fetch.
            for (EventData obj : execute) ;
        } finally {
            if (mgr != null) {
                mgr.close();
            }
        }

        return CollectionResponse.<EventData>builder()
                .setItems(execute)
                .setNextPageToken(cursorString)
                .build();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "unused"})
    @ApiMethod(name = "listUserEventData")
    public CollectionResponse<EventData> listUserEventData(
            @Nullable @Named("username") String username,
            @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

        EntityManager mgr = null;
        List<EventData> execute = null;

        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();
            Query query = mgr.createQuery(String.format("select from EventData as EventData where BelongsTo = '%s'", username));
            Cursor cursor;
            if (cursorString != null && cursorString.trim().length() > 0) {
                cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
                query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
            }

            if (limit != null) {
                query.setFirstResult(0);
                query.setMaxResults(limit);
            }

            execute = (List<EventData>) query.getResultList();
            cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
            if (cursor != null) cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

            // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
            // for lazy fetch.
            for (EventData obj : execute) ;
        } finally {
            if (mgr != null) {
                mgr.close();
            }
        }

        return CollectionResponse.<EventData>builder()
                .setItems(execute)
                .setNextPageToken(cursorString)
                .build();
    }
    /**
     * This method gets the entity having primary key id. It uses HTTP GET method.
     *
     * @param id the primary key of the java bean.
     * @return The entity with primary key id.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "getEventData")
    public EventData getEventData(@Named("id") String id) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        EventData eventData = null;
        try {
            eventData = mgr.find(EventData.class, id);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return eventData;
    }

    /**
     * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
     * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
     * It uses HTTP POST method.
     *
     * @param eventData the entity to be inserted.
     * @return The inserted entity.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "insertEventData")
    public EventData insertEventData(EventData eventData) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try {
            if (containsEventData(eventData)) {
                throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
            }
            mgr.persist(eventData);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return eventData;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used for updating an existing entity. If the entity does not
     * exist in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
     * It uses HTTP PUT method.
     *
     * @param eventData the entity to be updated.
     * @return The updated entity.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "updateEventData")
    public EventData updateEventData(EventData eventData) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try {
            if (!containsEventData(eventData)) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
            }
            mgr.persist(eventData);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return eventData;
    }

    /**
     * This method removes the entity with primary key id.
     * It uses HTTP DELETE method.
     *
     * @param id the primary key of the entity to be deleted.
     * @return The deleted entity.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "removeEventData")
    public EventData removeEventData(@Named("id") String id) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        EventData eventData = null;
        try {
            eventData = mgr.find(EventData.class, id);
            mgr.remove(eventData);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return eventData;
    }

    private boolean containsEventData(EventData eventData) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        boolean contains = true;
        try {
            EventData item = mgr.find(EventData.class, eventData.getEventKey());
            if (item == null) {
                contains = false;
            }
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return contains;
    }

    private static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003093/method-interference-for-endpoint-with-google-eclipse-plugin

Comment: true, same issue, thanks for the link

Comment: welcome , actually i had posted the answer first than  i though its very commom issue it might be already asked by someone else than i got this and deleted my answer. Hope your problem got solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The end of the automatically generated path looks like this: `_ah/api/endpoint_name/version_name/return_type/{named_parameter_1}/{named_parameter_2}/…`

The problem you're facing is that both methods are in the same endpoint class, of the same version, have the same return type, and use `GET`. Therefore, the URLs will be identical and conflicting. In this case, they're both `_ah/api/eventdataendpoint/v1/eventdata`.

The solution is to add the [`path` attribute](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#attributes_1) to one of the classes, like so:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "listUserEventData", path="eventdata/user")
public CollectionResponse<EventData> listUserEventData(…
```

Now, the first method with have URL `_ah/api/eventdataendpoint/v1/eventdata` and the second one will have path `_ah/api/eventdataendpoint/v1/eventdata/user`.

As you increase the number of methods in your endpoint, you will come across conflicts like this a lot, so if you plan on making many new methods, it's a good idea to use the `path` attribute every time rather than rely on CE to auto-generate a path.

Edit: you'll find a lot of info pertaining to your API and each method's path at `YOUR_APP_ID.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/ENDPOINT_NAME/v1/rest`

Answer (score 0):

The Answer given by @willlma is definately right !
But a very simple way of fixing this temporarily and avoid a lot of code change is to add another named parameter to be passed in the method.

```
public Event getFirstEvent(@Named("mainEventId") Long mainEventId,
```

> @Named("useless") Boolean useless ,

```
User auth) throws UnauthorizedException {
                if (auth!=null){
                    ...
                    return event
                } else throw new UnauthorizedException("Please authenticate first.");
            }
    public Event getEvent(@Named("eventID") Long eventID, User auth) throws UnauthorizedException {
                if (auth != null) {
                    ...
                    return event;
                } else throw new UnauthorizedException("Please authenticate first.");
            }
```